# Цветовая модель HSV(HSB). Перевод из RGB

Tags: c#, wpf

Недавно сталкнулся с задачей, в одном элементе которой требовалось преобразование

rgb -> hsv.

Вначале хотелось сделать всё по общеизвестным формулам:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Но после увидел, что в System.Drawing.Color для этого имеются специальные методы, которые возвращают нужные мне параметры:

GetHue() - Gets the hue-saturation-brightness (HSB) hue value, in degrees, for this Color structure.
GetSaturation() - Gets the hue-saturation-brightness (HSB) saturation value for this Color structure.
GetBrightness() - Gets the hue-saturation-brightness (HSB) brightness value for this Color structure.

Казалось, что дело в шляпе, но не тут то было, поскольку, как видно по формулам, для чистых цветов, к примеру RGB(255,0,0), параметр B, то есть яркость, должен быть 100%, однако на деле, черезе метод GetBrightness() выходит лишь 50%.
Далее решил глянуть реализацию данных методов (что бы убедиться, что я не спятил):
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,23adaaa39209cc1f

как видно, возвращается не [max(r,g,b) / 255] * 100% , а среднее между максимальным и минимальным
так где же я неправ? или откуда взялись странные формулы, по которым реализованны данные методы, м.б. это ошибка разработчиков или же ошибаюсь я?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что HSB/HSV != HSL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Comment: почитал про hsl
да, вы правы, в коде используется именно представление hsl 
хотя и в документации пишется, что возвращаются параметры hsv/hsb

Comment: Их часто путают. Можете дополнить мой комментарий и разместить как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый человек, Kromster, в коментарии упомянул про модель HSL
и вот оно! 
хоть в документации и написано, что данные методы возвращают параметры для модели   HSB, однако значения считаются как раз таки для модели HSL.